# Firebase ignores catch/then when using signInWithEmailAndPassword inside NGXS Action

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, ngxs

I have an action that logs in the user via email and password:

```
export class LoginWithCredentials {
  static readonly type = '[Auth] Login With Credentials';
}
```

I dispatch this action whenever the login form has been submitted:

```
onSubmitLogin() {
  this.store.dispatch(LoginWithCredentials);
}
```

The action handler gets from the state the email and password and call `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`, like so:

```
@Action(LoginWithCredentials)
loginWithCredentials({getState}: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
  const {email, password} = getState().forms.login.model;

  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); // Should console.log on error

  console.log('Should print something');
}
```

For some reason, `catch` is being ignored, and the `console.log` that should print something, is ignored too.

I tried to run this method outside of the state, and it seemed to work. Although, I want to put this logic into my action.

PS:

if I use `signInWithPopup(provider)` instead of `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, then it will work (But it's not what I need).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you call an asynchronous function and as you are not waiting for the result then NGXS "consider the action over" (I do not know how it works behind the scene..).

If `signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns a promise try this :

```
@Action(LoginWithCredentials)
async loginWithCredentials({getState}: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {

  const {email, password} = getState().forms.login.model;

  await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); // Should console.log on error

  console.log('Should print something');

}
```

Anyway as it is asynchronous you need to wait the answer (success or failure) to update your state. Something like this:

```
@Action(LoginWithCredentials)
async loginWithCredentials({getState, patchState}: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {

  const {email, password} = getState().forms.login.model;

  const loginAnswer = await yourLoginService.login(email, password);

  if( loginAnswer === 'success' ) {
      patchState( { loggedIn: true };
  }

}
```

Comment: Using async/await was my first approach. Unfortunately, it didn't make any difference. As I mentioned, when I tried to call `signInWithPopup`,  The function **did** catch errors. My current workaround is to scope the promise inside try/catch, which is a bummer.